# Read specific portion of a file by counting line number in java platform

Tags: java, file, line-numbers

I want to read a text file in java. I know how to read line by line from a text file by java. My question is if I have a text file that has 500 lines. I  want to read the file from the 50th line to the 150th line by counting the line number first of the file. Can it be possible using LineNumberReader or any other class? I don't want to use `line.equals("something")` method.
I am a beginner.

So far, I tried:

```java
public class ReadLine{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("H://java//newFile.txt");
        try {
            LineNumberReader linenumber = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));
            linenumber.setLineNumber(50);
            String line = null;
            for (int i = linenumber.getLineNumber(); i < 151; i++) {
                System.out.println("line=" + linenumber.readLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NitinBisht thanks for your reply. I want to read 50th line to 150th line, total 100 lines.can it be possible?

Comment: yes it is possible. There can be many ways. You can refer mentioned link and you may require to change the code slightly as per your requirement

Comment: @NitinBisht could you help me by providing the correct solution?

Comment: Can you at least provide what **you have** tried?

Comment: @DevilsHnd I have just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `setLineNumber()`. It just changes the value returned by `getLineNumber()`, it doesn't skip anything in the input stream. The **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`LineNumberReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html), says so explicitly:

> Note however, that `setLineNumber(int)` does not actually change the current position in the stream; it only changes the value that will be returned by `getLineNumber()`.

To only process some of the lines from the file, simply add an `if` statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("H://java//newFile.txt");
    try (LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
            if (reader.getLineNumber() >= 50 && reader.getLineNumber() <= 150) {
                System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber() + ": " + line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, with an upper limit on line number, there is no reason to keep reading after that, so you should do it like this:

```
File file = new File("H://java//newFile.txt");
try (LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        if (reader.getLineNumber() > 150)
            break;
        if (reader.getLineNumber() >= 50) {
            System.out.println(reader.getLineNumber() + ": " + line);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need to know the line number, then with Java 8+ Streams, it's even easier:

```java
Path file = Paths.get("H://java//newFile.txt");
Files.lines(file).limit(150).skip(49).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.That is what I really want to